# How could I inline a node_modules script in a Gatsby website?

Tags: webpack, gatsby

I'd like to inline the whole UMD module source code of `https://zizzamia.github.io/perfume/` in a Gatsby website, how could I read it from the `node_modules` directory and place it into the `<head>` of the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following solution:

- install [raw-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader), a webpack loader to import a
  file as a string

```sh
npm install raw-loader --save-dev
```

- import my file as a string

```
import rawPerfume from 'raw-loader!./node_modules/perfume.js/dist/perfume.umd.min.js';
```

- I created a plugin (simply add a `plugins/<PLUGIN_NAME>` to the root of the project) containing a
  `gatsby-ssr.js` file (take a look at the [SSR guide of
  Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/ssr-apis/))
- then I set one more head component

```
import React from "react";
export const onRenderBody = ({
  setHeadComponents,
}) => {
  setHeadComponents([
    React.createElement('script', {
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML: {
        __html: rawPerfume.default || rawPerfume
      }
    })
  ]);  
}
```

The final code is something like this (`plugins/gatsby-plugin-perfume.js/gatsby-ssr.js` file)

```
import rawPerfume from 'raw-loader!./node_modules/perfume.js/dist/perfume.umd.min.js';

import React from "react";
export const onRenderBody = ({
  setHeadComponents,
}) => {
  setHeadComponents([
    React.createElement('script', {
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML: {
        __html: rawPerfume.default || rawPerfume
      }
    })
  ]);  
}
```

You can see the code on [the gatsby-plugin-perfume.js plugin](https://github.com/NoriSte/gatsby-plugin-perfume.js) I've shared too